# Find a way around wordpress sitemap plugin limitations

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

I created a [blog](http://www.kopodium.com) using wordpress in January.

Though, I use a custom template for one of my page to display custom dynamic pages. (exemple [here](http://www.kopodium.com/results/nation/taekwondo/1_60/france))

Now, I use the wordpress plugin XML-Sitemap to automatically generate **sitemaps**. 
Unsurprisingly, this plugin does not crawl the page using a custom template, and the many links within.

However, I thought that the crawlers of the major search engines would do so. But they didn’t. My custom pages are still not indexed anywhere.

So here is my question:

- I have found a tool that can comprehensively crawl my website and generate a sitemap. If I use it, do I have to de-activate my wordpress pluging?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i'm not experienced in Word Press, but I came out with two ideas about your problem, so, if they could be useful, here are:

1) I don't think the plugin crawls the template. Instead I think the plugin generates the sitemap starting from the sitemap saved in the wordpress configuration (in drupal the sitemap and url aliases are saved in the database for example, and the sitemap plugin starts from there)

2) If your plugin generates a sitemap file (I think it does!), so you have to disable it first of use an other tool

Hope it helps!